# Javascript objects not being defined in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, undefined

I have one file which contains this function:

```
$(function () {
    window.selected = {};
    const pageFilter = new PageFilter(); <-ERROR HERE
    const filters = JSON.parse(pageFilter.toString());

    [do other stuff]
});
```

And in another file I have my `PageFilters` class defined as such:

```
class PageFilter {
    constructor() {
        if (typeof window.Filters === "undefined") {
            window.Filters = {};
            window.pendingNotifications = [];

            const columnFilter = Util.getParameterByName("columnFilter");
            const trimedFilter = columnFilter.substring(1, columnFilter.length - 1);
            if (trimedFilter.length > 0) {
                const parsedColumnFilter = JSON.parse(trimedFilter);

                this.addRange(parsedColumnFilter);
            }
        }
    }

...[more methods etc.]
}
```

And when I run my entire project in chrome or firefox, i don't get any errors, however when I run it in Internet Explorer, I get an error when I try to create a new `PageFilter()` object.

Anyone have any insight as to why I might be getting this error only in ie and no other browsers? Any possible fixes?

I'm also having a similar issue in another area of my code where I try to call another javascript class from a cshtml file, and it also says that it is undefined but only in ie. Any insight on this would be great, thanks!

Comment: Which JS framework are you using? And are you using typescript?

Comment: Are these files getting called from the HTML in the correct order? Have you considered using `defer` to guarentee the scripts order?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript classes are a core part of the ES6 language feature set.

Those are not directly supported in IE, you need to transpile your code first.

[Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is the go-to transpiler for ES6.